# Cannot close bootstrap tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing a weird problem in which I'm unable to close bootstrap tags.
Below is my html code,

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="searchTags" data-role="tagsinput"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using Bootstrap V3.0.

Below is the screen shot of the tags,

[image]

As you can see from the image that 'x' used to close the tags is not displayed. Any idea why??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is chrome console/firebug saying anything about errors?

Comment: @JochemQuery nothing showed there.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing this css file:

```
  <link href="bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is my Source and it works with the closing x:

```
<html>
    <head>

    <link href="bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="searchTags" data-role="tagsinput"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

(I didn't took care of nice use of js/css folders)

Let me know if this helps